# Classes and Sub-Classes using the 'this' variable

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm trying to attach a class method to an element so that it references that instance of the class.

//EXAMPLE

```
class Default{
    constructor(){
        this.parent = null
    }

    assemble(){
        var form = document.createElement('form'); //CREATE FORM ELEMENT
        var btn = document.createElement('button'); //CREATE BUTTON ELEMENT
        this.parent = form; //DECLARE PARENT (CONSTRUCTOR)
        btn.type = 'button';
        btn.innerHTML = 'click me';
        btn.addEventListener('click',this.submit);
        form.appendChild(btn);
        return form;
    }   
}

class Form extends Default{
    submit(){
        console.log(this.parent); //should return instantiated form value for property parent but doesn't (undefined)
        console.log(this); //returns reference to the button element itself not the class (Form)
    }
}
```

//CALLED

```
var route={
    init:()=>{      
        var form = new Form();
        var formBuild = form.assemble();
        document.body.appendChild(formBuild);
    }   
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',route.init);
```

**Question:** Why is the Form class method `submit()` returning the button element itself and not the instantiated class?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmMpzN?editors=1111) with your code and everything works as I would expect it to. What exactly is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @Dario I'm trying to have the button return the parent which would be the form element in this example `this.parent` but `this` doesn't refer the instantiated object at all.

Comment: Just to make sure, in the code pen I linked `this.parent` references the form itself but you want `this` to return the form as well?

Comment: @Dario no, so your codepen example calls the `submit` method on the form object, where my example calls it via a click event on the button element.

Comment: The problem is merely how you bind the `submit` method and how `this` is decided when it's called. `btn.addEventListener('click', this.submit.bind(this))`

Comment: @deceze yeah thats exactly what I was looking to do, I just feel if that is the case and you have to bind the method every time, you might as well just create a global function outside the class. What your thoughts on that `bind()` vs. global function?

Comment: No. The fact that context is decided at *call time* is a quirk of JavaScript you need to understand and accept; don't throw out OOP with the bath water just for that.

Comment: @deceze yeah good point. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
class Default{
    constructor(){
        this.parent = null
    }

    assemble(){
        var form = document.createElement('form'); //CREATE FORM ELEMENT
        var btn = document.createElement('button'); //CREATE BUTTON ELEMENT
        btn.parent = form; //DECLARE PARENT (CONSTRUCTOR)
        btn.type = 'button';
        btn.innerHTML = 'click me';
        btn.addEventListener('click',this.submit);
        form.appendChild(btn);
        return form;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Change btn.parent = form; //DECLARE PARENT (CONSTRUCTOR)

Comment: Did you change anything in the code? Why does that work and why didn't the original code? Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation.

Comment: Bergi, I changed from  this.parent = form; //DECLARE PARENT (CONSTRUCTOR) to  btn.parent = form;

Comment: this.parent to btn.parent

Comment: But why? Now it's doing the wrong thing.